# Newline in tableOutput for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
myDf <- data.frame(doc = c(1, 2, 3), text = c("Statement 1: ok<br/> Statement 2: not ok", 
"Statement 1: true\n Statement 2: false", "Statement 1: yes Statement 2: no"))
```

Which I would like to render as the following in a `shiny` app:

```
doc text
1   1   Statement 1: ok
        Statement 2: not ok
2   2   Statement 1: true
        Statement 2: false
3   3   Statement 1: yes Statement 2: no
```

However, each time I try (either using `br` or `\n`) the text is rendered verbatim.

Code for Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  myDf <- data.frame(doc = c(1, 2, 3), text = c("Statement 1: ok<br/> Statement 2: not ok", "Statement 1: true\n Statement 2: false", "Statement 1: yes Statement 2: no"))

  output$dfTable <- renderTable({ myDf })
}




ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(tableOutput("dfTable"))
)



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have found [one](http://www.r-bloggers.com/preventing-escaping-in-html/) webpage that mentions this issue, but discusses it more in the context of `rmarkdown` and `mustache`.
[Another](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/getting-line-breaks-with-xtable-td868387.html) discusses this in context of `Latex`.

Answer (score 0):

They way I got this working was to create the table using shiny `tags` and then rendering the the HTML. It doesnt come with the standard styling so it will require CSS to make the table how you would like. However, I came across these `tags` when I required dynamic dropdowns generated from MySQL db. Anyway, the below code may get you on your way.

```
myDF <- tags$table(tags$tr(tagList(mapply(tags$th,c("doc", "text"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
                           )
                    ),
           tags$tr(tags$td(1), tags$td(tags$ul(tagList(mapply(tags$li,c("Statement 1: ok", "Statement 2: not ok"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))))),
           tags$tr(tags$td(2), tags$td(tags$ul(tagList(mapply(tags$li,c("Statement 1: true", "Statement 2: false"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))))),
           tags$tr(tags$td(3), tags$td(tags$ul(tagList(mapply(tags$li,c("Statement 1: yes", "Statement 2: no"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))))
                   )
```

creates the required HTML. Below is the `shiny` part. Note you have to change from `renderTable` to `renderUI`.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$dfTable <- renderUI({ myDf })
}




ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(tableOutput("dfTable"))
)



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Would love to know if this could be achieved without resorting to building the HTML.